# How to use capitalization when name is unknown

Tags: capitalization, epithets

When using a vague descriptor for a character, like *the man* or *the silhouette*, should I capitalize any part of these terms?

EG:
The shadowy figure walked across the room. They picked up their hat and dusted it off. I knew that the shadowy figure liked their hat - OR - The Shadowy Figure walked across the room. They picked up their hat and dusted it off. I knew that The Shadowy Figure liked their hat.

Comment: I think [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) is better suited for a question like this, as it seems to me it is up to the author to decide such a thing.

Comment: Your use of ***The** Shadowy Figure* is mistaken. You should NOT capitalize articles even when the noun they apply to is capped. Just because tipping the Pizza Guy is important never makes him ***THE*** Pizza Guy. He's only ever the Pizza Guy. Don't capitalize articles.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is the custom to capitalise only proper nouns - eg of names of people, places, days of the week, months of the year (e.g. *it will take place on a Saturday in March*) etc.

When using common nouns, one does not normally capitalise (e.g. *...the woman helped the child cross the road*)

However if for some reason a particular descriptive form were used to name someone, perhaps because their real name was unknown - it would not be unusual to use capitals (e.g. *...the Man in the Iron Mask suddenly came into view.*)

Titles are of course proper nouns, when used to indicate the person holding one - hence we talk about the Queen, the Prince of Wales etc - also President Biden, Sir Mo Farah, Lord Newby, Baroness Bakewell or Doctor Strangelove.

Comment: I would say:  "We watched the Queen on television last night."

Comment: @GEdgar Of course there are all kinds of proper nouns, such as titles, places, streets, bridges etc. But the question didn't seem to call for an exhaustive list of categories of proper nouns. I have however edited to include titles of people.

Comment: Same applies to kinship terms, which act like titles. Capitalized example: "Is **M**om here?" Non-capitalized example: "My **m**om is here." (At least, that's the style my mom taught me.) However, for non-kinship titles, I believe one offten capitalizes the words, even when they are not functioning as names, but just as descriptors. E.g. "The Vice President disagreed with the President."

Comment: @Brandin Re the last sentence - I think that is correct so far as you are referring to a specific person. But in a sentence such as "Nowadays a male president would stand a better chance with a female vice-president" - I would not capitalise either title. But if you said "On 6 January 2021 the Vice-President refused to do the President's bidding" you would be referring to known people - hence capitalisation would be required.